# Calculate stock returns - when in position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dateframe with returns on a certain stock. Sometimes there is a position in this stock, and sometimes there is no position.
When there is no position, the result should stay the same (just cash).

But when there is a position, the cash amount should change. How do I calculate this without using a loop?

I use this for calculating the stock return for each row, with 1 when there is no position and perc_change when there is :

```
df['change']= np.where(df.pos>0, (df.close.pct_change() + 1), 1)
```

For the cash column I have:

```
nomdf['cash'] = 0
nomdf.cash.iloc[0] = 10000
nomdf.cash.loc[1:] = nomdf.cash.shift(1) * nomdf.change
```

```
                      close  pos  change     cash
date                                             
2018-01-19 15:30:00  26.830  0.0     1.0  10000.0
2018-01-19 15:31:00  26.940  0.0     1.0  10000.0
2018-01-19 15:32:00  26.910  0.0     1.0      0.0
2018-01-19 15:33:00  27.025  0.0     1.0      0.0
2018-01-19 15:34:00  27.035  370.0     1.0003      0.0
```

but desired outcome is something like this:

```
                      close  pos  change     cash
date                                             
2018-01-19 15:30:00  26.830  0.0     1.0  10000.0
2018-01-19 15:31:00  26.940  0.0     1.0  10000.0
2018-01-19 15:32:00  26.910  0.0     1.0  10000.0
2018-01-19 15:33:00  27.025  0.0     1.0  10000.0
2018-01-19 15:34:00  27.035  370.0   1.0003  10003.0
```

It seems I need to loop this to get this kind of code working, meaning I'm doing something wrong. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
nomdf.cash = np.cumprod(nomdf.change) * 10000
```

Output:

```
                date   close    pos  change     cash
2018-01-19  15:30:00  26.830    0.0  1.0000  10000.0
2018-01-19  15:31:00  26.940    0.0  1.0000  10000.0
2018-01-19  15:32:00  26.910    0.0  1.0000  10000.0
2018-01-19  15:33:00  27.025    0.0  1.0000  10000.0
2018-01-19  15:34:00  27.035  370.0  1.0003  10003.0
```

---

The reason why your code doesn't work becomes clear when you look at the output of `nomdf.cash.shift(1)
2018-01-19        NaN
2018-01-19    10000.0
2018-01-19    10000.0
2018-01-19        0.0
2018-01-19        0.0`: it does one shift and that's it. For your code to work you need the shift in each cycle after the update of the cash value.